# Show page after Angular2 render it

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I'm working on migrating site to the Angular2. One of the pages contain Slick carousel ([Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)). Data for slides of this carousel received from the RESTful API (links to the images, text etc.). So I have template which looks like next:

```
<div class="slider">
    <div *ngFor="let slider of skill?.Slider; let first = first">
        <a class="item active" href="{{ slider.SlideLinkUrl }}">
            <img src="{{ slider.SlideImageUrl }}" alt="{{ slider.Title }}" />
            <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
            <div class="slider-text">
                <div class="slider-text_author">
                    <img src="{{ slider.SmallImageUrl }}" alt="{{ slider.Name }}" /></div>
                <p class="slider-text_page">{{ slider.Title }}</p>
                <p class="slider-text_name">{{ slider.Name }}</p>
                <span class="slider-text_name__prof">{{ slider.Description }}</span>   
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where skill - object received from RESTful API using Observable.
To create carousel I have to call function using jQuery:

```
jQuery(".slider").slick(slickOpts);
```

I've tried to call this function from `ngAfterContentInit`, `ngAfterViewInit` but template not rendered with info received from server yet, so carousel not working. To postpone call of the carousel initialization i did next ugly hack in `ngOnInit` function:

```
this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    let id = params['id'];
    this.skillService.getSkill(id).subscribe(s => {
        this.skill = s; console.log(this.skill); Observable.timer(1, 1).take(1).subscribe(() => this.initSlider());
    }, error => console.log(error)
    );
});
```

Here call of `initSlider()` postponed on 1 millisecond after data from server received. It works but there is visible "jump" when page firstly rendered without carousel and then in one moment carousel added.

So, the question is - what is the right way to show page only after carousel initialized? Is it possible to stay on previous page while render or just show clear background?

Comment: for this usecase i think you can play with `CanActivate` hook to check if you get data from API. If you get then redirect to carousel component else don't redirect.

Comment: use promise instead of observables

Comment: @rashfmnb I've tried to use Promise instead of Observable but still getting same result.

Comment: I'm trying to use this carousel with Angular2 too and I realized it doesn't like the *ngFor. Did you find any solution?